# Issues accessing and running code in try catch blocks

Tags: java, methods, try-catch

For some reason, my program will not write to the file, even though I was able to get the try catch blocks to be error free and to run. Is there a reason why I cannot access the try blocks and create this file?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader crunchifyBuffer = null;
    try {
        String crunchifyLine;
        crunchifyBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/moo/Desktop/test.csv"));
        // How to read file in java line by line?
        while ((crunchifyLine = crunchifyBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            ArrayList<String> parsedData = new ArrayList<String>();
            parsedData.add(crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(crunchifyLine).get(0));
            parsedData.add(crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(crunchifyLine).get(7));
            parsedData.add(crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(crunchifyLine).get(8));
            System.out.println("\n"+ parsedData + "\n");
            String ID = parsedData.get(0);
            String[] aVPayload = new String[3];
            aVPayload[0] = ID;
            String holder = sdkCall(aVPayload);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(holder);

                String Lat = jsonObj.getJSONObject("geo").getString("latitude");
                String Long = jsonObj.getJSONObject("geo").getString("longitude");


                try {
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("addressValidityReport.txt", "UTF-8");
                    writer.println("ID" + "\t" + "CSV Lat" + "\t" + "CSV Long" + "\t" + "Lat" + "\t" + "Long" + "\t" + "Status" );
                    while ((crunchifyLine = crunchifyBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        writer.println((crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(crunchifyLine).get(0)) + "\t" + (crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(crunchifyLine).get(7)) + "\t" + (crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(crunchifyLine).get(8)) + "\t" + Lat + "\t" + Long + "\t" + "FLAGGED" + "\n");
                    }
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR, CHECK FILE PRINTING!");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("unexpected JSON exception");
            }


        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {

            if (crunchifyBuffer != null) crunchifyBuffer.close();
        } catch (IOException crunchifyException) {
            crunchifyException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It runs, but no file gets created. Would having two catch exceptions cause this?

Comment: If you're getting no exceptions thrown, then is your CSV file empty?

Comment: nope it is populated, when I make the try catch section that contains PrintWriter independent it would create the file, but then would not have access to the 'Lat' 'Long' String variables and I would have to null them.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using your debugger? This will enable you to see exactly what each of your variables it set to at each point in the code.

Comment: Unless you're restricted to pre Java 7, you should use try-with-resources to make sure that your writers and readers are closed properly.

Comment: yeah, I have stepped through the debugger, i made some changes on the structure of the code, but it still seems very odd that it didn't run correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a writer.flush() before close(), forcing the data to be written to the file

PrintWriter(File file, String csn)
Creates a new PrintWriter, **without** automatic line flushing, with the specified file and charset.

After checking the printl() method, I think that It will not make a flush() and you are probably loosing your data, and thats why you don't have your file at the end